# elasticsearch query with multiple categories

Tags: elasticsearch, categories

So I'm trying to query movies by genre or category.

And in my document each movie could have 1 or more categories.

```
{
    title: 'title1',
    genre: ['Horror', 'Action', 'Adventure']
},
{
    title: 'title2',
    genre: ['Action', 'Comedy']
}
```

and so on.. 
I would like to query it by giving multiple genre types and want to match the best one.
ex) query movies matching action, comedy -> match the ones that have the most genres matched in their genre field. It doesn't have to be an exact match. So I basically want to find the document that has the most match with my multiple genre input.

Anyone have any inputs? The document could be constructed differently. 
thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Terms Query** you find a document with multiple input

```
GET <index_name>/_search
    {

      "size": 20,
      "query": {
          "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "genre": [
                  "horror",
                  "action"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: so this means it has to have horror and action right? so eventually I'm going to pass in like horror, action, comedy, fantasy and want to find the movie that matches the most? If I do must then it means it has to contain all of the fields right? Let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: the above query just return the documents which matches the horror and action genre . if you want sort result by most matched use functional score https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html